# Android AlarmManager not waking phone up (with or without WakeLock)

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I've been trying to make a simple alarm app for a while, but I've never had any success getting the phone to wake up (with or without a WakeLock). This is my code for MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final int sleepRequest = 111;
    public final int wakeRequest = 222;

    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    AlarmManager manager;

    // currently no difference between sleeping and waking alarms, nor do the alarms use the selected time

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button sleepButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sleepButton);
        sleepButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                createAlarm(sleepRequest);
            }
        });

        Button wakeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wakeButton);
        wakeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                createAlarm(wakeRequest);
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAlarm(final int requestCode) {
        showTimePicker(new Completion() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(int hour, int minute) {
                setAlarm(hour, minute, requestCode);
            }
        });
    }

    public void showTimePicker(final Completion completion) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        completion.onCompletion(hourOfDay, minute);
                    }
                }, hour, minute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }

    public void setAlarm(int hour, int minute, int requestCode) {
        Date date  = new Date();
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.setTime(date);

        Calendar alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
        alarm.setTime(date);
        alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        if(alarm.before(now)){
            alarm.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        }

        manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, requestCode, intent, 0);
        manager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

For AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        Log.i("SimpleWakefulReceiver", "Starting service @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }
}
```

For AlarmService:

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {
    public AlarmService() {
        super("AlarmService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("APP", "in onHandleIntent");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello world", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And this is the AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.me.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver
            android:process=":remote"
            android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".AlarmService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

When it reaches the time the alarm is supposed to go off, I get this error:

```
11-07 20:52:01.106 20764-21883/com.me.app I/APP: in onHandleIntent
11-07 20:52:03.136 20764-20775/com.me.app W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {f9c4a9b} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {f9c4a9b} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                                                                      at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:543)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:326)
                                                                      at android.widget.Toast$TN.hide(Toast.java:738)
                                                                      at android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub.onTransact(ITransientNotification.java:11-07 20:52:01.106 20764-21883/com.me.app I/APP: in onHandleIntent
11-07 20:52:03.136 20764-20775/com.me.app W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {f9c4a9b} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {f9c4a9b} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                                                                      at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:543)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:326)
                                                                      at android.widget.Toast$TN.hide(Toast.java:738)
                                                                      at android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub.onTransact(ITransientNotification.java:55)
                                                                      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)55)
                                                                      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

Comment: don´t forget doze mode: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: Changing `setExact` to `setAndAllowWhileIdle` doesn't make a difference, and I don't think the phone even stays idle long enough to activate doze mode. (The alarm is set for barely a couple seconds after the button is pressed.)

Comment: oh, havent seen this....you need the permission: `com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't make a difference.

Comment: If the toast is showing, then the alarmManager should work. Have you done anything with the calendar that is not posted here?

Comment: Yes, the AlarmManager seems to be working, but the WakeLock/whatever mechanism wakes the phone up isn't. If I put the phone to sleep before the toast shows, nothing happens. This is all the code I have.

Comment: I guess you are missing to use this with a service. See the docs, you should do it the way the recommend: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: I added the service, but now it complains about a handler being on a dead thread. I'll update the original post in a bit with the new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing what WakefulBroadcastReceiver does.  It doesn't turn on the screen.  It wakes up the processor.  If you want to turn on the screen, you need to use a normal broadcast reciever and take a full wakelock-  the wakelock that WakefulBroadcastReceiver takes is a partial one.

Comment: I tried adding a wake lock, but even though I'm using the flag `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` (which I'm sure is valid), it complains that I need to specify a valid wake lock level.

Comment: Then specify a valid level.  That isn't a level, that's a flag. You need to OR it with a level.  THe level you'd need to wakeup the screen is SCREEN_DIM_WAKELOCK, SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKELOCK, or FULL_WAKELOCK depending on the brightness you want for the screen and keyboard.

Comment: Those values are deprecated, though.

Comment: They're still what you need. They're deprecated because they prefer you to use the activity based flags, but since you aren't launching an activity that isn't possible

Comment: Alright, I got it to work using `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK`, then starting the Activity from the service and disabling the keyguard. Thanks!